# Why is there no article before "use" in "indefinitely suspended use of the vaccine"?

Tags: articles, definite-article, zero-article

This is a sentence from Wikipedia, from article on Astra-Zeneca vaccine:

> On 14 April, the Danish Health Authority indefinitely suspended use of
> the vaccine.

Why not "the use" is used here?

Answer (score 2):

It would be perfectly fine with "the," but it's not necessary. The statement is about use of the vaccine in general and so it's not necessary (but perfectly acceptable) to further specify which use is intended with an article. When a word isn't necessary, it's often best in terms of style to leave it out.

Comment: I was taught that in English an article is mandatory always before a noun.

Comment: You were unfortunately taught [wrong](https://www.vedantu.com/english/omission-of-article)!